# How safe is IPtables whitelisting?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, linux-networking, hacking

I am deploying some VPS and of course, security is a big concern.
I read that IPtables whitelisting is the best way to safeguard your machine.
So I set up the follwing :

```
echo "Flushing rules"
iptables -F
echo  "Allow localhost interface"
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

echo "Allow local network traffic"
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -j ACCEPT

echo "Allow my dear friend 1"
iptables -A INPUT -s xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT

echo "Allow my dear friend 2"
iptables -A INPUT -s xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT

echo "Allow already established connections"
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

echo "Set default policies"
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

How safe is this setup? In what ways could a potential hacker break my firewall ( of course provided the hacker is outside my local lan )?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When you set your default policy to `DROP` and `ACCEPT` only what you need, this is clearly more secure than allowing everything by default and selectively `DROP` unwanted traffic types.

This at least saves you from securing the services that are not meant to be accessed remotely (from outside your machine or your LAN).

Your system is more secure when you expose less services to outside world.

Comment: Makes sence! By the way..should I move my policies before the allows, or does order of rules not make a difference?

Comment: If you are running them in a script, there is no difference. However, you will lock-up yourself when you set policies to drop before allowing your access!

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks good. You should look over `iptables-persistent` to make your firewall start up automatically after VPS reboot. It works really well (it is just a service which start in boot time and modify firewall with saved ruleset).